# Creating a Vector calculator append function. Attempting to add any value to it

Tags: c

So I'm having some more trouble with my vector calculator here and I'm not entirely sure of how I can get a float value to append to a vector.  The append function is made and works properly, but the only problem I have is a case of "What if the user wants to put a 0 in the vector?"

Right now, I'm using a check to see if the float is 0, but obviously it doesn't work because it will split out an invalid operand.  Is there anyway I can see if a float value is either not entered, or is not a number? So far, here's a fragment of the part I'm having trouble with:

```
//Vector that is intialized
Vector * myVector = alloc_vec();
//character for the options
char optionSelect[100];
//character that picks out the selection.
char select;
//A float for the operations that require an option.
float myScales = 0;

printf("Please enter a selection: ");
fgets(optionSelect, 100, stdin);
sscanf(optionSelect, "\n%c%f", &select,&myScales);

...

else if(select == 'a')
{
    if(myScales != 0)
        {
            myVector = extend_vec(myVector, myScales);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("No operand specified.\n");
        }
}
```

What can I do to make sure any float value from -inf to inf can be added in, but invalid things such as letters or no input right after 'a' is selected?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, if you set myScales to 0.0/0.0 to get a NaN(presumably?) number, and check myScales == myScales followed by the rest, and set myScales back to 0.0/0.0 it should work!